# How to select more than one maximum (or minimum) value from a vector in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to obtain the three largest number in a vector, with R.
With function max() I can get the first one, is there any function that I can choose the number of values that I want?

For example:
vector <- c(100,215,200,180,300,500,130)
max(vector)

This will returne 500,
I want something that returns: 500, 300, 215.

I've tried

pmax(vector,3)

Comment: `tail(sort(vector),3)`

Comment: `sort(vector, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `tail` function to get the last three elements of the sorted vector.

Example:

```
largest_three <- tail(sort(vector), 3)
```